# Merge the tag "test" with the tag "testing"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

It seems that [test](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/test) and [testing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/testing)  should be set as synonyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updating post history, 22 rows affected
updating posts, 21 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 13 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [testing] and [test] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym test -> testing was approved!
```

Done!